# Where in this statement is the reverse triangle rule used?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta, triangle-inequality

I've attached part of a proof from my lecture notes (the proof is showing that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$), it makes reference to using the reverse triangle rule in an important step, but I really don't see what it is being used on.[image]

Comment: If $|x-a|<\delta<|a|/2$ then $||x|-|a||<|x-a|<\delta<|a|/2.$

Comment: $||x|-|a||<|a|/2$ is used to show $|a|/2<|x|<3|a|/2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis in red

$$\lvert x - a \rvert \lt \delta \le \frac{\lvert a \rvert}{2}.$$

Hence using the reverse triangle inequality

$$\lvert \lvert x \rvert - \lvert a \rvert \rvert \le \frac{\lvert a \rvert}{2}$$ which implies

$$-\frac{\lvert a \rvert}{2} \le \lvert x \rvert - \lvert a \rvert \le \frac{\lvert a \rvert}{2}$$ and finally the desired conclusion.

Comment: Can you explain to me how we go from the second inequality to the third, please?

Comment: By definition of the absolute value, for $b \gt 0$, $\lvert x \rvert \lt b$ means $-b \le x \le b$. This is exactly what I used here.

Comment: I see now, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x-a|<\frac{|a|}2$, then $\bigl||x|-|a|\bigr|<\frac{|a|}2$. So:

- since $|x|-|a|\leqslant\bigl||x|-|a|\bigr|$, $|x|-|a|<\frac{|a|}2$;
- since $|a|-|x|<\bigl||x|-|a|\bigr|$, $|a|-|x|<\frac{|a|}2$.

Therefore$$\frac{|a|}2<|x|<\frac{3|a|}2.$$

Comment: Why is it the case that $|x|-|a| \le ||x|-|a||$ is true?

Comment: Because we always have $x\leqslant|x|$.